# Github account not linked despite using ssh key

Tags: git, github

I just got a new laptop and set up my github account with a new ssh key. However, whenever I commit to a repo, it says that the user that made the commit is `Jimmy Lastname <jimmy@Jimmys-MacBook-Pro.local>`. Why is it saying this instead of saying my normal github account made the commit? I linked the ssh key from my computer to my github account. Thanks.

Comment: The commit messages are from your local git configuration, at the point in time when you did the commit, not the push.

Comment: How do I check the local git configuration? The only file on my computer I see is `~/.gitconfig` and all it declares is to `excludesfile = /Users/jimmy/.gitignore_global`

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-your-dvcs-username-for-commits/ something like this?

Comment: Got a video on global and local identity setup. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6RTjhkNjWI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it saying this instead of saying my normal GitHub account made the commit?

Because you have not set your user.name/email:

```
git config --global user.name <MyGitHubAccount>
git config --global user.email <my@email.com>
```

Since there was no settings, Git try and guessed your user name/email based on your local computer account.